# Is every computer in IBM's fleet based on superconductivity?

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices, superconducting-quantum-computing

I'm currently writing my thesis and I'd like to know which computer is based on a superconductive architecture to run some simulations.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are you only interested in the systems from IBM? I'm about 95% sure that those are all transmon-based, as are the ones from Google & Rigetti.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. IBM uses superconducting Transmon qubit. Here is a quote from [IBM's website](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/quantum-computing-at-ibm/):

> At the heart of IBM quantum systems is the transmon qubit. Successive generations of IBM Quantum processors have demonstrated the potential of superconducting transmon qubits as the basis for electrically controlled solid-state quantum computers. With a scalable approach to chip architecture and research into error correction and mitigation, IBM Quantum is at the forefront of developing systems with sufficient quantum volume to demonstrate advantage in real world applications.

Maybe you are looking for something like this list:

[image]

Comment: Oh well, thank you! This'll be very usefull.

Comment: Just to add that Quantum Inspire offeres two quantum processors, one based on transmon and one on electron spins.

Comment: @MartinVesely Yeah. Good point!! Here is the link: https://www.quantum-inspire.com/